# :except options in routes that contain collections and members not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Currently the route exceptions are still showing up when I run `rake routes`.

```
resources :userhome, :except => [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :show, :destroy] do
  collection do
    post :create_invitation
  end
  member do
    get :edit_profile_picture
    post :update_profile_picture
  end
end
```

How can I make the exceptions work?

Comment: @basicxman, do you want to take a shot at this?

Comment: Please post result of `rake routes` for userhome (`$ rake routes | grep userhome`). Isn't it more simple to use `:only => [:index]` instead of `:except => [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :show, :destroy]`?

Comment: @Hck, i thought using :only would negate the other routes that were defined but i'll give it a try. I'll edit the question to include the routes after i give your suggestion a go.

Comment: Thanks, @Hck. Not only did it not eliminate the other routes i defined but it also worked to eliminate the routes i was trying to create an exception for. I wonder why :only worked and :except did not. If you post an answer with your suggestion i'll mark it as the best answer to my question. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jay, :only will generate Rest routes [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy] for your resources without specified ones in :only option. All other routes will stay untouched.

Comment: @Jay, I need at least to see what routes are generated for userhome (if possible - one result with :expept option specified and another with :only option).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A simpler way to eliminate unneeded routes is by specifying the `:only` option

```
resources :userhome, :only => [:index]
```

instead of

```
resources :userhome, :except => [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :show, :destroy]
```